# android disable move to next field

Tags: android, tabs, android-edittext, field, move

In my android application I have several editTexts in a linear layout. Then I have several spinners below them in the same linear layout. If a spinner item is selected it jumps back up to one of the edit text fields. I would compare it to pressing tab when your filling out a webform, it automatically jumps to the next field. That would be fine except it jumps back closer to the top of the layout and the user has to scroll back down to click the submit button. Is there any way to disable the automatic move so the application won't force a move to the next field?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if there is an easy way to disable it entirely. But you can control which views get focus next by setting the

```
android:nextFocusRight
android:nextFocusLeft
android:nextFocusUp
android:nextFocusDown
```

attributes in your layout xml. You would set them ="@+id/idOfTheNextView"

Comment: Metion: just set self to be the next focus, `android:nextFocusDown="@id/self_id"`, then the current edittext keeps the focus.

Answer (score 4):

Although late by years here but you can use this setting on the EditText

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

Comment: This is the perfect Solution for this Scenario!